# find the best combination with algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, tabu-search

I have 49 points and I want to find the best combination for `n` selection from 49 points to maximize my objective function. my objective function is linear `Zc =max(f1 - ωf2)`. for example I want to find best 10 points which The objective function is maximized with these 10 points. `f1` is nash-sutcliffe model efficiency which is calculated by using the interpolated points for `all_points` and selected points that is  `candidate_1`.`ω` is weighting coefficient that get value `0.3`  and `f2` is Ratio of selected points to total points(10/49) .so my objective function has range [-∞,1] and The closer the objective function is to `1` the more optimal the answer.so I assumed `K` be interpolated value for `candidate_1` and `j` interpolated value for `all_point` and `L` is mean of `j`. I use this framework to calculated `f1` and objective function.

```
all_points = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]
candidate_1 = [3,6,11,12,14,17,19,23,28,43]
#calculate f1 and f2
```

[f1 equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esw8P.jpg)

```
f2 = 10/49
#calculated objecive function
Zc = f1 - 0.3*f2
#print objective function value
Zc = 0.59

#next step is to create another candidate that improve Objective function
```

so as you can see for `candidate_1` my objective function is `0.59` As you know, there are many options for choosing 10 out of 49. I must create another candidate and And  I have to keep doing this until the target function reaches its maximum value and does not change much after that.I need a code structure to make smart candidates to improve my objective function

Comment: please simplify your question to only provide the numerical application (we do not need to know what `ω` is but we need its value. Also provide a minimal example with the expected output.

Comment: Can you calculate the value of each after weighting and applying the function, sort, then have your output? If not, please try and explain your answer in a better light for other readers.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Nash-Sutcliffe model efficiency coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash%E2%80%93Sutcliffe_model_efficiency_coefficient) shows me a horrible formula. Is this what you're using? How does this formula apply to your model? You included the comment `calculate Objective function` in your code. Can you do that? Can you maybe write a small code that makes a few selections at random, and calculates f1 and f2 for each of those selections, then keep the best one?

Comment: Can you please check again? I added more details.@mozway

Comment: yes I can calculate nash_sutcliffe its not my problem. I also added more details to make problem understandable. I'm looking for a code that cleverly selects candidates  to bring my objective function closer to the maximum.@Stef

Comment: yes I can.I added more details to make the problem understandable. I just looking for code that select smart candidate in each iteration.@LarrytheLlama

Comment: "L is mean of j" .. so j is an array, and L is a number, right? If so.. how `math.pow((j-L),2)` work.. ?

Comment: @p._phidot_. yes both j and k are array and j is number. I modified the `f1` equation check it again.

Comment: "K be interpolated value for candidate_1 and j interpolated value for all_point" > so K & j IS an array (of different length), and L is a number. | In the corrected equation K & L is an array (of the same length), and j is used as a number.. | or I get it wrong..

Comment: @p._phidot_ after creating  interpolation raster with `candidate_1` and `all_points` I extract their values on grid point so k and L have same length and j is mean of values for for all grid point which Created by interpolation using `all_points` and its number. so the second part of your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: Then @Stef " write a small code that makes a few selections at random, and calculates f1 and f2 for each of those selections, then keep the best one" suggestion is good to go.. what's stopping u? (I mean.. where d u get stuck then?) The algorithm is clear, just code it, run. U will get the wanted "another candidate that improve Objective function" at every run (provided we didn't repeat any).